# Hosting OData Service

Tags: unix, odata

Is it possible to host a Odata Service in Hosting Unix ? thanks

Comment: this question is very vague and probably does belong on serverfault. Please think about specifying a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitly possible, as OData is simply based on any data source combined with a json/atom view.

You could tackle this problem by using a combination of MYSql as Data source, Tomcat as webserver and Apache Olingo for providing the odata feed.

This is just one possible solution, as you can exchange any of the parts.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. The os hosting the service is irrelevant. Odata is more about an implementation of the odata protocol. This can be done in any language you choose. Now, if what you are asking is whether you can host a WCF data service (which implements the odata protocol) on a linux box I would have to venture a guess. and my guess would be no.